Proper time is invariant but undefined at the event horizon in schwarzschild metric. How can we remove this problem with a coordinate transformation?
We know that the line element gives us the proper time taken to traverse “nearby” coordinates.This is an invariant as well, so how can we remove the issue of undefined proper time at the event horizon in the schwarzschild metric by a coordinate transformation?

The infinite proper time needed to move off the event horizon is physical.

But doesn’t a particle cross the horizon in finite proper time?

Possibly useful: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/327323/

@Shaashaank it crosses the horizon in finite proper time from its own frame of reference. An observer at rest with respect to the black hole will see the particle stop at the event horizon and get slowly redshifted until it is no longer observable. This also happens in finite proper time, but this proper time depends on the maximal wavelength the measuring apparatus can detect.

@paulina thank you for the reply! I understand the point that it takes a finite amount of proper time. But that wasn’t my doubt. The answer by Dale was what i was looking for and the ensuing comments, if you are interested.

Can someone please fix the spelling of "Schwarzschild" in the title and the body of the question?

@mkrieger1 done


so how can we remove the issue of undefined proper time at the event horizon in the schwarschild metric by a coordinate transformation?

A coordinate chart is a smooth invertible mapping between an open subset of the manifold and an open subset of R4. The Schwarzschild chart does not cover the event horizon. There is no coordinate transform to or from the Schwarzschild chart at the horizon because the chart itself does not cover the horizon.
In other words, the issue is not that proper time is undefined at the event horizon in the Schwarzschild chart. The issue is that the Schwarzschild chart itself does not exist at the event horizon.
This is not something that can be removed nor does it need to be removed. We can simply use a chart that does cover the horizon to calculate any invariant we wish to calculate at the horizon. There is no need (nor any possibility) to transform to a chart that doesn’t cover it.

No, this is very wrong. It is standard to point out that the event horizon is a coördinate singularity, and is totally removable by going to nicer coördinates. Then the integral that OP wants to do, can be done all the way to the physical singularity. The correct argument against the OP is that the integrand, proper time, is well-defined despite the coördinate chart being technically bad; that is, when we use the nicer coördinates that does not have a singularity at the event horizon, the proper time integrand is still momentarily zero at the event horizon. That is perfectly fine.

Oh wait, I see what it is you are trying to say now; you are actually saying the same thing, but the wording is so awkward. Why would you want to emphasise the badness of the chart at the event horizon rather than just assert that there are better coördinates that smoothly extend from outside the EH to inside?

@naturallyInconsistent it is not wrong. I would point you to the freely available Lecture Notes on General Relativity by Sean Carroll.  https://arxiv.org/abs/gr-qc/9712019  See in particular chapter 2. The fact that the coordinate singularity is removable by going to a different chart is the whole point of the last paragraph. But the reason you have to do that is because the standard chart doesn’t cover the horizon.

Yeah, it took me a bit of time to realise that we are saying the same thing.

Thank you so much for your time! I understand this but then can we not say the same for the r=0 singularity? That the coordinate chart itself doesnt exist there and there could be some other chart where that exists?

@naturallyInconsistent The point of emphasizing the badness of the chart at the horizon is to show exactly where the question is based on a false premise

@Shaashaank that would certainly be something we could say about the singularity if there were a chart defined at the singularity. One difference that we can point to between the horizon and the singularity as that in the limit as you approach the singularity some curvature invariants increase without bound but the same limits at the horizon are all finite. This leads us to believe that there are no such charts at the singularity

@Dale so just to confirm, the curvature invariants that we check out are also a limit? We dont actually find them at either of the singularities? And since they blow up at one point and not at the other as a limit, we see a difference? If this is correct, then it makes perfect sense! Thank you!

@Shaashaank in charts that are defined at the horizon we can also calculate the curvature invariants at the horizon and show that all of the invariants are continuous at the horizon. But we don’t need to do that direct calculation to see this difference between the horizon and the singularity. The limit is sufficient

So for example kruskal coordinates is one where i dont need to find the limit, i could just find the actual value whereas for schwarszchild i can only find the limit. That makes sense!
